# How can I return to back page after create django?

Tags: django

After Create moneylog, I want to got back to moneybook_detail, so I made a **moneylog/View.py**:

```
class moneylog_create(FormView):

    form_class = forms.CreateMoneylogForm
    template_name = "moneylogs/create.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        moneylog = form.save()
        moneybook = moneybook_models.Moneybook.objects.get(
            pk=self.kwargs["pk"])
        form.instance.moneybook = moneybook
        moneylog.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return redirect(reverse("moneybook:detail", kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs["pk"]}))
```

and this is **Moneybook/urls.py**

```
app_name = "moneybooks"

urlpatterns = [
    path("create/", views.moneybook_create.as_view(), name="create"),
    path("update/<int:pk>/",
         views.moneybook_update.as_view(), name="update"),
    path("<int:pk>/", views.moneybook_detail, name="detail")
]
```

How can I return to moneybook_detail after create moneylog?

Comment: replace moneybook to moneybooks: return redirect(reverse("moneybooks:detail", kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs["pk"]}))

Comment: what error you are getting.

Comment: @SaisivaA No error, but it doesn't return to backpage(moneybook detail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class moneylog_create(FormView):

    form_class = forms.CreateMoneylogForm
    template_name = "moneylogs/create.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        moneylog = form.save()
        moneybook = moneybook_models.Moneybook.objects.get(
            pk=self.kwargs["pk"])
        form.instance.moneybook = moneybook
        moneylog.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return redirect(reverse("moneybooks:detail", kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs["pk"]}))


app_name = "moneybooks"

urlpatterns = [
    path("create/", views.moneybook_create.as_view(), name="create"),
    path("update/<int:pk>/",
         views.moneybook_update.as_view(), name="update"),
    path("detail/<int:pk>/", views.moneybook_detail, name="detail")
]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it doesn't work.. I don't know what is your intention for changing <int:pk> to detail/<int:pk>

Comment: moneybooks:detail :- moneybooks should be name of the app, and url constructs **moneybooks/detail/5/** or you can use moneybooks/5/

Comment: And try to execute the **reverse("moneybooks:detail", kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs["pk"]})** on terminal.

Comment: although I didn't understand right before I re-reply your comment, I did actually what you said, and it didn't work. though, Thanks for your comments. I understand what you said.. but it didn't work anyway

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a model form instead of FormView, use Create view and correct your return as shown

```
 class moneylog_create(CreateView):
    form_class = forms.CreateMoneylogForm
    template_name = "moneylogs/create.html"

def form_valid(self, form):
    moneylog = form.save()
    moneybook = moneybook_models.Moneybook.objects.get(
        pk=self.kwargs["pk"])
    form.instance.moneybook = moneybook
    moneylog.save()
    form.save_m2m()
    return reverse("moneybooks:detail", kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs["pk"]})
```

and use **non overlapping pattern** in url

```
path("moneybook/<int:pk>/", views.moneybook_detail, name="detail")
```

and your create view is `moneylog_create` where as you mentioned in url as `moneybook_create`

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it doesn't work.. i don't know what is non overlapping pattern in url.

Comment: what error you are getting, can you post the trace back

Comment: No error, "POST /moneylogs/create/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5132" is log message but there is no page redirect.

Comment: you just erase redirect, but there is no change when i edit my code like yours..

Comment: instead of FormView try with CreateView which is more specific to the purpose

Comment: I think CreateView is not basic solution... and also doesn't work... anyway Thanks for reply!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206681/discussion-between-dhooonk-and-bmons).